# Magento 2 Braintree Payment Gateway Issue - Error Message Not Displayed on Failed Transactions

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, braintree, gene-braintree

We're running Magento version 2.4.5-p1 and utilizing the Braintree payment gateway for both credit card and Paypal transactions.

Our concern is that when a customer attempts to place an order and the transaction fails due to insufficient funds, there is no error message being displayed at checkout.

According to our expectations, an error message should appear in such cases. Has anyone encountered this issue before or can offer insights into potential solutions?

Is anyone aware about this ?